# Volume of a fillet by revolution

Tags: calculus, integration, solid-of-revolution

I try to figure the volume of
[a fillet (rounded angle of radius r) obtain by revolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EidwH.jpg)

I used the shell method and at one point, I need to solve a part of the integral with the form:

$$
V = 2\pi\int_{0}^{r}{\left(u + r\right)
\,\sqrt{\,{r^{2} + u^{2}}\,}\,\mathrm{d}u + \mbox{etc}}
$$

it's been a while since i haven't dealed with stuff like that, any idea please $?$.

Comment: would you be so kind and mark my answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a substitution:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\text { substitute } u=r \tan (s) \text { and } d u=r \sec ^{2}(s) d s . \text { Then } \sqrt{r^{2}+u^{2}}=\\
&\sqrt{r^{2} \tan ^{2}(s)+r^{2}}=r \sec (s) \text { and } s=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{r}\right)\\
&=2 \pi r \int r \sec ^{3}(s)(r \tan (s)+r) d s
\end{aligned}
$$

Factor out constants:
$=2 \pi r^{2} \int \sec ^{3}(s)(r \tan (s)+r) d s$

Expanding the integrand $\sec ^{3}(s)(r \tan (s)+r)$ gives $r \sec ^{3}(s)+r \tan (s) \sec ^{3}(s):$
$=2 \pi r^{2} \int\left(r \sec ^{3}(s)+r \tan (s) \sec ^{3}(s)\right) d s$

Integrate the sum term by term and factor out constants:
$=2 \pi r^{3} \int \tan (s) \sec ^{3}(s) d s+2 \pi r^{3} \int \sec ^{3}(s) d s$

For the integrand $\tan (s) \sec ^{3}(s),$ substitute $p=\sec (s)$ and $d p=\tan (s) \sec (s) d s$
$=2 \pi r^{3} \int p^{2} d p+2 \pi r^{3} \int \sec ^{3}(s) d s$

The integral of $p^{2}$ is $\frac{p^{3}}{3}$ :
$=\frac{2}{3} \pi p^{3} r^{3}+2 \pi r^{3} \int \sec ^{3}(s) d s$

Use the reduction formula, $\int \sec ^{m}(s) d s=\dfrac{\sin (s) \sec ^{m-1}(s)}{m-1}+$
$\dfrac{m-2}{m-1} \int \sec ^{-2+m}(s) d s,$ where $m=3:$
$=\frac{2}{3} \pi p^{3} r^{3}+\pi r^{3} \tan (s) \sec (s)+\pi r^{3} \int \sec (s) d s$

The integral of $\sec (s)$ is $\dfrac{\log (\tan (s)+\sec (s))}{G}$
$=\dfrac{2}{3} \pi p^{3} r^{3}+\pi r^{3} \tan (s) \sec (s)+\pi r^{3} \log (\tan (s)+\sec (s))+c o n s t$
STEP 11
Substitute back for $p=\sec (s):$
$$
=\dfrac{2}{3} \pi r^{3} \sec ^{3}(s)+\pi r^{3} \tan (s) \sec (s)+\pi r^{3} \log (\tan (s)+\sec (s))+\text { constant }
$$

Substitute back for $s=\tan ^{-1}\left(\dfrac{u}{r}\right)$
$=\dfrac{2}{3} \pi r^{3} \sec \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{r}\right)\right)^{3}+\pi r^{3} \tan \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\dfrac{u}{r}\right)\right) \sec \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{r}\right)\right)+$
$$
\pi r^{3} \log \left(\tan \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{r}\right)\right)+\sec \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{r}\right)\right)\right)+\text { constant }
$$

Simplify using $\sec \left(\tan ^{-1}(z)\right)=\sqrt{z^{2}+1}$ and $\tan \left(\tan ^{-1}(z)\right)=z:$
$x$
$=\pi r u \sqrt{r^{2}+u^{2}}+\frac{2}{3} \pi\left(r^{2}+u^{2}\right)^{3 / 2}+\pi r^{3} \log \left(\sqrt{\frac{u^{2}}{r^{2}}+1}+\frac{u}{r}\right)+$ consta

Factor the answer a different way:
$=\frac{1}{3} \pi \sqrt{r^{2}+u^{2}}\left(2 r^{2}+3 r u+2 u^{2}\right)+\pi r^{3} \log \left(\sqrt{\frac{u^{2}}{r^{2}}+1}+\frac{u}{r}\right)+$ consta

Which is equivalent for restricted $u$ and $r$ values to:
Answer:
$$
=\frac{1}{3} \pi\left(\sqrt{r^{2}+u^{2}}\left(2 r^{2}+3 r u+2 u^{2}\right)+3 r^{3} \log \left(\sqrt{r^{2}+u^{2}}+u\right)\right)+\text { constant }
$$

This is the solution to the indefinite integral, you can plug in your values then